# trouble finding eulers multiplier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(2x+y+1)dx+x(2y+x-1)dy=0$$
I tried to find eulers multiplier for this differential equation but i cant seem to find a solution using u=x, u=y, u=xy.